# Optimizing an SQL query that utilizes Entity Attribute Value (EAV) tables, which add significant time

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, relational

My goal on this post is to provide only the information needed and see if it is possible to optimize this query.  Here is the query itself:

```
FLUSH TABLES;
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
  nl.id,
  nl.node_id,
  nl.name,
  nl.parent_name,

  nlv.status,
  nlv.version,
  nlv.code,
  nlv.region_id AS region

  -- added fields if specified
   ,IF(ISNULL(nf_youtube_id.value), '', nf_youtube_id.value) AS youtube_id
   ,IF(ISNULL(nf_brightcove_id.value), '', nf_brightcove_id.value) AS brightcove_id
   ,IF(ISNULL(nf_youku_id.value), '', nf_youku_id.value) AS youku_id

FROM
  node_lists nl
  JOIN node_list_versions nlv ON nlv.node_list_id = nl.id
  JOIN node_versions nv ON nl.node_id = nv.node_id AND nlv.region_id = nv.region_id

  -- added field joins if specified
    LEFT JOIN node_fields nf_youtube_id ON nf_youtube_id.node_version_id = nv.id AND nf_youtube_id.name = 'youtube_id'
    LEFT JOIN node_fields nf_brightcove_id ON nf_brightcove_id.node_version_id = nv.id AND nf_brightcove_id.name = 'brightcove_id'
    LEFT JOIN node_fields nf_youku_id ON nf_youku_id.node_version_id = nv.id AND nf_youku_id.name = 'youku_id'
WHERE
  nl.model_type = 'Resource'
  AND ((nl.name LIKE '%') OR (nlv.code LIKE '%'))
GROUP BY
  nl.node_id, nlv.region_id
ORDER BY 
  status asc LIMIT 0, 1000000
```

So the stats on the tables are:

- `node_lists`: innoDB, 10,400 records
- `node_list_versions`: innoDB, 199,600 records
- `node_versions`: innoDB, 12,065 records
- `node_fields`: innoDB, 205,900 records

Although all the tables are innoDB, there are no actual constraints between the keys.  No `REFERENCES`, ON UPDATE CASCADE, etc..  I do have `btree` indexes on all the join and where clause fields (that much I understand).

The query takes about 2.5 seconds without the join/fields from the `node_fields` table, and `LEFT JOIN`ing each instance of `node_fields` adds about a half second on this particular query.

Is there ANYTHING I can do to optimize this query, especially any glaring omissions?  For reference, an `EXPLAIN (that query)` yielded the following:

```
select_type table         type possible_keys                                                        key                               key_len ref           rows  filt  Extra
SIMPLE      nl            ref  PRIMARY,node_lists_model_type_index,node_lists_node_id_index         node_lists_model_type_index           194   const           7624     100    Using temporary; Using filesort
SIMPLE      nv            ref  node_versions_node_id_index,node_versions_region_id_index           node_versions_node_id_index              4   db.nl.node_id      1     100    NULL
SIMPLE      nlv           ref  node_list_region_node_list_id_index,node_list_region_region_id_index node_list_region_node_list_id_index     4   db.nl.id          17    6.25    Using where
SIMPLE      nf_youtube_id ref  node_fields_node_version_id_index,node_fields_name_index             node_fields_node_version_id_index         4 db.nv.id           7     100    Using where
SIMPLE   nf_brightcove_id ref  node_fields_node_version_id_index,node_fields_name_index             node_fields_node_version_id_index         4 db.nv.id           7     100    Using where
SIMPLE      nf_youku_id   ref  node_fields_node_version_id_index,node_fields_name_index             node_fields_node_version_id_index         4 db.nv.id           7     100    Using where
```

I can't see where I'm missing anything or indexes are incomplete.  It seems like .5 seconds for each `LEFT JOIN` of `node_fields` is just too much?  How can I improve this?

Comment: Please give actual DDL & example data.Per [mcve]. It would be helpful if you could describe the straightforward relationships/associations/tables (columns, constraints, example data, etc) that given EAV data is encoding including any special properties (tree? graph?). PS Why LIKE '%'?

Comment: A given entity-attribute pair only has one value. So (entity, attribute) is a PK in an EAV table. Did you tell the DBMS? Presumably ditto for entity-attribute-version. Please act on my last comment.

Comment: We really need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to discuss this further.  [_EAV sucks_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav), and most people fail to put [_good indexes on the attribute table_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta).